# Автоматическая отправка формы

Tags: php

В скрипте А подключается  обработчик Робокассы, содержащий форму и кнопку отправки, как сделать, чтобы при подключения обработчика Робокассы мы отправляли форму автоматически, без нажатия на кнопку Оплатить.
Подключение В: `include($arResult["PAY_SYSTEM"]["PATH_TO_ACTION"]);`
Содержание В (в сокращенном виде):

```
<form action="http://test.ru" method="post" target="_blank">
<input type="hidden" name="FinalStep" value="1">
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="<?=GetMessage("PYM_BUTTON")?>">
</form>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какой CMS используешь?

Comment: @MichaelPak битрикс. Мне нужно чтобы сначала производилась оплата, а потом уже перекидывало на страницу с оформленным заказом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если прямо в лоб, то например костыль на `js` добавить обработчик:

```js
$(function(){
    $('form#acquiring').submit();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="acquiring" action="http://test.ru" method="post" target="_blank">
    <input type="hidden" name="FinalStep" value="1">
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Отправить">
</form>
```

Но есть вероятность блокировки такого действия из-за политики безопасности браузера, сейчас точно не помню. Надо проверять.

### UPD

И есть небольшая вероятность отключения `JS` на клиенте, как заметил @Sergiks.

Comment: И есть ничтожная вероятность отключённых скриптов – стоит предусмотреть такой вариант и убедительно попросить юзера нажать кнопку.